# @SpringBootTest with MapStruct requires Impl

Tags: java, spring-boot-test, mapstruct

I have following test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeService.class, DtoMapperImpl.class})
class SomeServiceTest {
```

And following mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface DtoMapper {
    EntityDto toDto(Entity entity);
}
```

I'm not changing packages (this means **DtoMapperImpl** is in the same package as **DtoMapper**)

As soon as I change Impl to interface my test fails:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeService.class, DtoMapper.class})
class SomeServiceTest {
```

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'someService': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'DtoMapper' available: expected at least 1
> bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Can you please advise best way solving this? I'm on MapStruct 1.3.1.Final

Comment: Because you are using `@SpringBootTest` wrong. That is for spring boot integration tests, you want to test your service then don't use `@SpringBootTest` for that.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer my question

Comment: As stated you are using the wrong tool for the job or you are using the tool wrong in this case. You either write a full integration test (and then remove the `classes` part) OR you write a simple unit test for your service and manually inject the mapper by obtaining it from MapStruct itself.

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to point out that your comments are off topic in this question. If you want to discuss ideology, how to write integration tests, I will be happy to do so outside of this question. Mods, please cleanup

Comment: It isn't about ideologie it is about using the wrong tool for your test, which is what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224152/discussion-between-tillias-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem actually has nothing to do with MapStruct, but rather to how `SpringBootTest#classes` is used.

The `classes` in `SpringBootTest` is meant to provide your components that should be used to load in the test.

From the JavaDoc:

> The component classes to use for loading an `ApplicationContext`. Can also be specified using `@ContextConfiguration(classes=...)`. If no explicit classes are defined the test will look for nested `@Configuration` classes, before falling back to a `@SpringBootConfiguration` search.
> Returns:
> the component classes used to load the application context

In your case you have 2 classes:

- `SomeService` - which I assume is a class annotated with `@Service` and Spring will correctly load it
- `DtoMapper` - this is the MapStruct mapper which is an interface and it isn't a component. The component which you want for your tests is `DtoMapperImpl`

You have several options to fix this:

### Use the Impl class

You can use the `DtoMapperImpl` (the Spring Component class) in your `SpringBootTest#classes`, your test will then load the correct component

### Use a custom configuration class that will component scan your mappers

```
@TestConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.example.mapper")
public class MappersConfig {

}
```

And then use this in your `SpringBootTest#classes`. E.g.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeService.class, MappersConfig.class})
class SomeServiceTest {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I posted earlier.  Can you please copy my code sample in the 2nd option and I'll mark this as answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a little improvement for accepted answer so that you don't have to write package name as hard-coded string, but use ComponentScan basePackageClasses instead:

```
@TestConfiguration
// @ComponentScan("some.package.mapper")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = DtoMapper.class)
public class MappersConfig {
}
```

But there is an obvious drawback in this (as well as accepted answer) approach: the whole package will be scanned which may contain undesired classes.

Answer (score 0):

Create following configuration (should point where mappers are):

```
@TestConfiguration
@ComponentScan("some.package.mapper")
public class MappersConfig {
}
```

And modify slice:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeService.class, MappersConfig.class})
class SomeServiceTest {
```